# LVM thin snapshot unavailable

Tags: lvm, fedora-22

To test out thinly provisioned snapshots before applying them to a production system for backup purpose, I did the following:

```
lvcreate -L1G -T storage/thinpool
lvcreate -V10M -T storage/thinpool -n thinvol1
lvcreate -V10M -T storage/thinpool -n thinvol2
# [create ext4 fs on thinvol1, mount it, add some files]
lvcreate -s --name snap1 storage/thinvol1
```

All commands succeeded, but when `lvdisplay storage/snap1` gives as status `NOT available` and `\dev\storage\snap1` is not created by the device mapper:

  `--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/storage/snap1
  LV Name                snap1
  VG Name                storage
  LV UUID                csDP34-HlpY-Rd8x-yJgr-99PW-jHZu-T7wsUJ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-11-24 10:01:43 +0100
  LV Pool name           thinpool
  LV Thin origin name    thinvol1
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                12.00 MiB
  Current LE             3
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto`

`lvchange -a y storage/snap1` made no difference either. Did I just miss a final step to make the snapshot accessible? Or what else could be the problem here?

OS: Fedora 22 (x64)
Kernel: 4.2.6-200.fc22.x86_64
LVM2: 2.02.116

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, thin snapshot are set as not available and with the "skip activation" bit set.

Try issuing `lvchange -ay -Ky storage/snap1` and your thin snapshot should become available.

To permanently set off the "skip activation" flag, issue `lvchange -kn storage/snap1`

Comment: Oh good God!  I see why this is needed logically, but it's still a pain.  Also, I'm going to have to break the "thank you" rule and say THANK YOU!  I spent a while on this one.  I'm using so many VMs these days that I've got to start using thin provisioning and such to save space.  EDIT: Nice logo!!  Ahh, good ole commies.

Comment: @DanielSantos do you know why this is logically needed? I dont understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: [ -K|--ignoreactivationskip ] is not even in the old man pages https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvchange

Comment: @user1133275 hehe, I'm a little late, but I'm going to guess it's to prevent accidental use of a thin snapshot that is intended to be a backup of something.  That's the only thing I can think.  It would have been nice to document the rationale.